# calculate multiple t-tests for all the combinations of 2 list elements in R tidyverse environment

Tags: r, purrr, t-test

I am looking for a way to calculate multiple t-tests for all the combinations of 2 list elements in R tidyverse environment.

I would like to test the means of Miles/(US) gallon based on Transmission for each combination of cyl and vs. My working example is this code:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl==8 & vs == 0) %>%
  mutate(am = as.factor(am)) %>%

  # independent t-test
  t.test(mpg ~ am, data = ., paired = FALSE)%>%
  broom::tidy() %>%

  mutate(cyl = 8) %>%
  mutate(vs  = 0)   %>%
  select(cyl, vs, everything())
```

I wrote this piece of code:

```
cyl_list <- list(unique(mtcars$cyl)) # 6 4 8
vs_list  <- list(unique(mtcars$vs))  # 0 1


complete_t_test <- function(cyl_par, vs_par){

  mtcars %>%
    filter(cyl=={cyl_par} & vs == {vs_par}) %>%
    mutate(am = as.factor(am)) %>%

    # independent t-test
    t.test(mpg ~ am, data = ., paired = FALSE) %>%
    broom::tidy() %>%

    mutate(cyl = {cyl_par}) %>%
    mutate(vs  = {vs_par})   %>%
    select(cyl, vs, everything())}
```

I was thinking of something similar to `purrr::map2(cyl_list, vs_list, complete_t_test)`
 but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List columns may be a viable solution (see book [R for Data Science, chapter 25](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)). I create a list column using `nest()`, then do the t-tests, and `unnest()` again to see the results.

NB: Your example fails for several combinations in the mtcars data, and therefore I use `possibly()` to do the t-test only if appropriate data are available.

```r
library("tidyverse")

f1 <- possibly(~t.test(mpg ~ am, data = .x), otherwise = NULL)

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl, vs) %>% 
    nest() %>%                                 # create list columns
    mutate(res = map(data, ~f1(.x))) %>%       # do t-tests
    mutate(res = map(res, broom::tidy)) %>%    # tidy()
    unnest(res) %>%                            # unnest list columns
    select(1:8)                                # show some columns for stackoverflow
#> # A tibble: 2 x 8
#> # Groups:   cyl, vs [2]
#>     cyl    vs           data estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <list<df[,9]>>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     4     1       [10 x 9]   -5.47       22.9      28.4    -2.76   0.0254
#> 2     8     0       [14 x 9]   -0.350      15.0      15.4    -0.391  0.704
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Write a function which calculates `t.test` between one combination. Use `cross_df` to create all combinations and apply the function `complete_t_test` to each combination.

```
library(tidyverse)

complete_t_test <- function(cyl_par, vs_par) {
   tryCatch({
      mtcars %>%
       filter(cyl== cyl_par & vs == vs_par) %>%
       t.test(mpg ~ am, data = ., paired = FALSE) %>%
       broom::tidy()
   }, error = function(e) return(NA))
}

cyl_list <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
vs_list  <- unique(mtcars$vs)

cross_df(list(a = cyl_list, b = vs_list)) %>%
   mutate(t_test = map2(a, b, complete_t_test))

#     a     b   t_test           
#   <dbl> <dbl> <list>           
#1     6     0 <lgl [1]>        
#2     4     0 <lgl [1]>        
#3     8     0 <tibble [1 × 10]>
#4     6     1 <lgl [1]>        
#5     4     1 <tibble [1 × 10]>
#6     8     1 <lgl [1]>
```